# (Advice) Payment to wrong receiver

Tags: paypal

SO I have a website with an API that allows Person B to buy goods online from Person A (using my site as the gateway).
Person A has supplied the wrong payment ID and therefore Person B has sent the money to someone other than Person A. From what I know so far, the mystery receiver is possibly a non-existent account.

Since my gateway was used, I have a list of affected transactions, but is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

So basically the payments went to the unclaimed status as the receiving account doesn't even exist . In that case if the person B has paid via PayPal account then they can login to the PayPal account and cancel the payment from there .

But if some has paid via credit or debit card option on the PayPal page then you can call the PayPal to cancel out those payment manually .

If no action is taken on the unclaimed payments they will be reverted to the buyer after 30 days .

But yeah there is no api you can use to cancel them .

Comment: Is there any way PayPal would migrate the transactions? Or is that asking too much

Comment: The only thing you can do is if have access to the email address ( the one to which the payment was sent) , you can add that email address in your PayPal account , confirm that email ( PayPal will send a link to that email to confirm it) and once that email is confirmed your unclaimed payments will come thru in that account.